# How to make this script perform other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently found this expandable table with Jquery, it is very lightweight and awesome code. However, I need to make small changes to it, but I don't know how. If you take a looks at this [demo](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/20/Expand-table-rows-with-jQuery-jExpand-plugin.aspx) when you go clicking from the first row to the second, third, fourth...so on. The row just keeps on expanding, instead I need the in-active rows to contract. Meaning, when a user goes from click first row to second, then the previous one contracts..

I hope it is clear, and I would provide the code but you can see the source code, it is neat and [Here](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/20/Expand-table-rows-with-jQuery-jExpand-plugin.aspx) is the full tutorial.

thanks.

Ok, here is the code in [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MDfG8):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
        $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
        $("#report tr:first-child").show();

        $("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
            $(this).next("tr").toggle();
            $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
        });
        //$("#report").jExpand();
    });
```

​

Comment: Please post a sample of your HTML markup here, and how you are binding the expanding table plugin to it.

Comment: And, ideally, a [*live demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing your code in action. Make it easy for us to help you. =)

Comment: Also, on a side note OP - I think it's a bad idea to be using any third party code where the online documentation is practically non-existent. Agreed that the downloaded source may have beautiful and helpful examples, but is it really that hard to have it online?!

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle chaps http://jsfiddle.net/MDfG8/

Comment: Anyone, the question has been updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach, though I feel it could be somewhat simplified:

```
$('#report tbody tr:nth-child(odd)').addClass('odd');
$('#report tbody tr:nth-child(even)').addClass('even').hide();
$('tr.odd').click(
    function(){
        var that = $(this),
            next = that.next('.even');
        that.find('.arrow').toggleClass('up');
        next.toggle().siblings('.even').hide();
        $('.even:not(":visible")').each(
            function(){
                $(this).prev('.odd').find('.up').removeClass('up');
            });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MDfG8/3/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: Thanks I compare both your and second answers response, and yours actually does not delete the title when clicking on the rows, which is good... can you help me with my second request though?

Comment: ...what second request? It doesn't appear to be in your question, which is where it *should* be, for future visitors to make sense of the question, and the submitted answers.

Comment: Thank you, and I'm glad to have been of help! But, I wasn't intending my comment as a complaint, just a strongly-worded suggestion to include your second request (whatever it was, is or might be) into your *question*. That way I might be able to find it, as would future visitors. =)

Comment: Yea I know. Thanks, are you up for a freelance project? simple 100% Javascript codding?

Comment: That depends on what it is, but if you send the details to my email address (check my user-page here) I'll definitely take a look.

Comment: Hi again, I am sorry asking this, but I copy/pasted all the codes a local html file, but the code is not working. I am doing something wrong? I created a .js files, downloaded jquery 1.7.2, created the css and html file, but the all the rows are expanded, and no way to click onto them

Comment: Have you wrapped the jQuery in a `$(document).ready(/* paste stuff in here */);`? Have you checked the error-console for illegal characters (JS Fiddle inserts bad characters (unicode character `8203`) presumably for formatting purposes).

Comment: No, I just downloaded the whole jquery only. I did not modify anything to it.

Comment: Is it online somewhere I can see it?

Comment: can you see anything on beminet.com I uploaded all files, must be my the browsers cache preventing me to see anything.

if you can't see the site here is the 
`jquery:` http://beminet.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js
`css:` http://beminet.com/css.css
`Js:` http://beminet.com/jExpand.js
`index:` view-source:http://beminet.com/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20036/discussion-between-david-thomas-and-eritrea)

Answer (score 3):

Change your click handler to this, which contracts everything before expanding the selected one:

```
$("#report tr.odd").click(function() {
    if ($(this).next("tr").is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next("tr").hide();
        $(this).find(".arrow").removeClass("up");
    } else {
        $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
        $(".arrow").removeClass("up");
        $(this).next("tr").show();
        $(this).find(".arrow").addClass("up");
    }
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/MDfG8/2/)

Comment: it was working for contracting the other items, but it wasn't contracting when you toggled the same element. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Thanks for the code, It works,  event the the caption disappears after clicking on the first row. thank you so much. One more thing though, I need to add inside each row a code that expands a little a truncated text and a href that says `more`, and when clicked it shows the rest of text. It is just like a facebook comment where when you click on the more.. like you see the rest of the comment. Do you have any idea where I can get a script like that, very very light one? Thanks

Comment: Google "jquery ellipsis" and you'll find a bunch of plugins.